# Error: nvarchar is incompatible with image vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2014

when I update table it gives me an error 'nvarchar is incompatable with image'
in my table, image fild datatype is an image

here is my code

```
Dim ms2, ms3, ms4, ms5, ms6 As New MemoryStream
        Dim arrPic1() As Byte = Nothing
        Dim arrPic2() As Byte = Nothing
        Dim arrPic3() As Byte = Nothing
        Dim arrPic4() As Byte = Nothing
        Dim arrPic5() As Byte = Nothing

        If PCTOA.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim bm2 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PCTOA.Image)
            bm2.Save(ms2, PCTOA.Image.RawFormat)
            arrPic1 = ms2.GetBuffer()
        End If
        If PctPO.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim bm3 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PctPO.Image)
            bm3.Save(ms3, PctPO.Image.RawFormat)
            arrPic2 = ms3.GetBuffer()
        End If
        If PCTChallan.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim bm4 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PCTChallan.Image)
            bm4.Save(ms4, PCTChallan.Image.RawFormat)
            arrPic3 = ms4.GetBuffer()
        End If
        If PCTInv.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim bm5 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PCTInv.Image)
            bm5.Save(ms5, PCTInv.Image.RawFormat)
            arrPic4 = ms5.GetBuffer()
        End If
        If PCTTC.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim bm6 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PCTTC.Image)
            bm6.Save(ms6, PCTTC.Image.RawFormat)
            arrPic5 = ms6.GetBuffer()
        End If
        'Query = "update companydetail set OASign=@ImageOA where companycode=@compcode"
        'Dim myCommand As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(Query, SQLDBCon)
        'myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageOA", arrPic1)
        'myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compcode", "1")
        'myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'SQLDBCon.Close()
        Query = "update companydetail set OASign=@ImageOA,POSign=@ImagePO,ChallanSign=@ImageChallan,InvoiceSign=@ImageInv,TCSign=@ImageTC where companycode=@compcode"
        Dim myCommand As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(Query, SQLDBCon)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageOA", arrPic1)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePO", arrPic2)
        If arrPic3 IsNot Nothing Then
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageChallan", arrPic3)
        Else
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageChallan", "0x00")
            'Dim p As New SqlParameter("@ImageChallan", SqlDbType.Image)
            'p.Value = "0x00"
            'cmd.Parameters.Add(p)

        End If

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageInv", arrPic4)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageTC", arrPic5)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compcode", "1")
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

here is my form

[image: Form image]

when I do not upload image in challan than in that field null value must be inserted.
Hows this possible.?
Can anyone help me?
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)
[Just don't](https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html)

Essentially you have no control over what SQL Server data type is being used here:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageChallan", "0x00")
```

To me, and to the code, "0x00" looks like a string.  So `AddWithValue` ends up using a string type, and the database is saying that's the wrong type.  Instead, specify the type explicitly.  Something like:

```
Dim param = New SqlParameter("@ImageChallan", SqlDbType.Image)
param.Value = DBNull.Value
myCommand.Parameters.Add(param)
```

That way you're specifying exactly the data type you want to use, and using `DBNull` for null values.